# Error while training a neural network model

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, numpy-ndarray, tf.keras

Here is the 2 files. I am getting error in train_model.py file while using the fit method

Model.py

```
def alexnet(width,height,outputs,lr):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(11, 11), strides=(4, 4), padding='valid', activation='relu',
                     input_shape=(width, height, 1)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=192, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))

    model.add(Dense(outputs,activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr),
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

train_model.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    WIDTH = 224
    HEIGHT = 224
    LR = 1e-3
    EPOCHS = 10
    OUTPUTS = 4
    # MODEL_NAME = 'racing_automation-{}-{}-{}-epochs-300K-data.model'.format(LR, 'alexnet', EPOCHS)

    model = alexnet(WIDTH, HEIGHT, OUTPUTS, LR)

    file = open('training_data_grid2019.pkl', 'rb')
    data = pickle.load(file)

    x = np.array([i[0] for i in data]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,1)
    y = [i[1] for i in data]

    X_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,random_state=42,test_size=0.2)

    **model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=(x_test,y_test), batch_size=32)**
```

Error :

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\GameAutomation\train_model.py", line 29, in 
model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=(x_test,y_test), batch_size=32)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\GameAutomation\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\GameAutomation\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1105, in select_data_adapter
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (<class 'list'> containing values of types {'(<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'int'>"})'})**

Tried almost everything and I am going nowhere. Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Looks like your input data is a numpy array that contains lists. Take a look at it.

Comment: what is `x.shape`?